# Using a global ResourceDictionary in a UserControl Library

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, global, resourcedictionary

I have have "Project A" with "MyResourceDictionary.xaml" in "App.xaml"

```
<Application.Resources>

    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

I want to also use "MyResourceDictionary.xaml" in my user control library - "Project B"

Can I do this?

Thanks,
Eamonn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [pack URI syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx). Something like:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="ProjectB;component/MyResourceDictionary"/>
```

Comment: Hi Kent, Thanks for the reply, think I am getting somewhere but I'm getting an error saying it cant find the resource dictionary :s

Answer (score 2):

@Kent Boogaart

Thanks for the help Kent, here is the working code

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/ProjectA;component/MyResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

anyone else having trouble with this check out this link - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx

Thanks,
Eamonn